# Cannot center navbar and logo with tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I wrote the styles in the code below with tailwind css for my navbar which made it all inline But I want all the content centered instead but don't know what corrections to make to the code that will help me achieve that. Please help me make my header centered with tailwind css

Header.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

import { getCategories } from '../services';


const Header = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories()
            .then((newCategories) => setCategories(newCategories))
        }, [])

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8 sticky top-0 z-10">
            <div className="border-b w-full inline-block border-blue-400 py-8">
                <div className="md:float-left block">
                    <Link href="/">
                        <span className="cursor-pointer font-bold text-4xl text-white">
                            Favourite Tech Solutions
                        </span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden md:float-left md:contents">
                    {categories.map((category)=>(
                        <Link key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
                            <span className="md:float-right mt-2 align-middle text-white ml-4 font-semibold cursor-pointer">
                                {category.name}
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: I added your code to Tailwind Play to see what it looks like, https://play.tailwindcss.com/Jbf9INo8Df but not following what you need. Do you want all the text on one line, but everything aligned to the centre?

Comment: No. Basically, the first div in the parent div with span containing 'favourite tech solutions' is the logo and the second div is the nav list. I want the first div on top and centered while the second div below and centered including every other items i will be adding to the nav in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present design
[image: Your present design]

Modified design
[image: Modified image]

According to your comment i guess this is what you wanted .

I did work-through using `flex` , the code goes like:

```
 <div>
  <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8 sticky top-0 z-10 bg-black">
    <div className="border-b w-full flex flex-col border-blue-400 py-4">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center my-1">
        <span className="cursor-pointer font-bold text-4xl text-white">
          Favourite Tech Solutions
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className=" hidden md:flex items-center justify-center ">
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <a key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
            <span className="md:float-right mt-2 align-middle text-white ml-4 font-semibold cursor-pointer">
              {category.name}
            </span>
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: However, the nav list disappears on small screen and I don't know how to fix that now

Comment: <div className=" hidden md:flex items-center justify-center "> change this to  <div className=" md:flex items-center justify-center "> remove the hidden property , Then nav list doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox will allow you to center the header easily:

```js
return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8 sticky top-0 z-10 bg-black">
      <div className="border-b flex justify-center items-center border-blue-400 py-8">
        <div className="md:inline-flex">
          <a href="/">
            <span className="cursor-pointer font-bold text-4xl text-white">
              Favourite Tech Solutions
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:inline-flex">
          {categories.map((category) => (
            <a key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
              <span className="md:float-right mt-2 align-middle text-white ml-4 font-semibold cursor-pointer">
                {category.name}
              </span>
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You can change the `justify-center` to `justify-between` if you prefer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but can you also help with a way I put a background color in the header on scroll? with tailwind if possible thanks